# how to generate a panel of 2 figs with \subfigures?

Tags: floats, subfig

I use `\subfigures` to replicate a panel of 2 figures (see below), and my output does not look like the one I wished to reproduce.

[image: the wished panel]

The output of my code is as follows:
[image: my output]

my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
         \centering
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/Fig_edited_figure_A_in_panel.png}
             \caption{}
             \label{fig: mHCN2_dime}
         \end{subfigure}
         \hfill
         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/mHCN2_cAMP_hidden_rotated_90_non-swapped_packing.png}
             \caption{}
             \label{fig: non-swapped_mHCN2}
         \end{subfigure}
         \hfill
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

is there a way to place them side by side while conserving the same size? if I had them beside each other, the figures get smaller.

i would also like to annotate the numbers and the arrow showing a 90° rotation, if that possible...

Comment: You can load the `floatrow` package &  use  the `subfloatrow` environment within figure.

Comment: First, I would reduce a bit the horizontal dimension of graphics. Say 0.47 `\textwidth` instead of 0.5. Now we have 0.5+0.5+space, and it is too much.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke this looks better now being side by side, any idea how to place (a) and (b) above like the picture i attached in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you like to reproduce top pair of subfigures. This can be simple dan by use of `floatrow` and `subfig` packages.

**Edit: **
Labels for sub figures had to be after inserted image and not  in rectangle parenthesis as was in the original Answer. Now is corrected (removed label out of space for captions).

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[figure]{subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf, 
            labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{2mm}
    \centering
\sidesubfloat[]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:mHCN2_dime} % <---
}
\hfill
\sidesubfloat[]%
{
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\label{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2} % <---
}

\caption{My figures}
\label{fig:fig:mHCN2}
    \end{figure}
See subfigures \ref{fig:mHCN2_dime} and \ref{fig:non-swapped_mHCN2} on figure \ref{fig:fig:mHCN2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what i wanted, do you know how to annotate like in the picture above?

Comment: @sphero, sorry, what you mean with `annotate`?

Comment: there are numbers and an arrow in the original image above, can one do that in LaTeX?

Comment: @sphero, of course, however, this should be part of "new" images where is this added. But this was not mentioned in your question, so answer solve only inserting of images and subcaption labels. You should ask new question (one problem for question, please), from which be clear, what is your problem or edit this question and make it much clearer.

Comment: @sphero, see edited answer.